# Sum of two tables with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, left-join

I have the query

```
SELECT c.user_id, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_bestof b WHERE b.user_id = c.user_id) as bCount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_pair   p WHERE p.user_id = c.user_id) as pCount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_style  s WHERE s.user_id = c.user_id) as sCount,

FROM   jos_findme c
```

how can I make a column with: bCount + pCount + sCount?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the column in your query:

```
   SELECT *,(bCount+pCount+sCount) as sumCount FROM(
    SELECT c.user_id, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_bestof b WHERE b.user_id = c.user_id) as bCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_pair   p WHERE p.user_id = c.user_id) as pCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_style  s WHERE s.user_id = c.user_id) as sCount,

    FROM   jos_findme c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(t.bCount+t.pCount+t.sCount) As TotalCount , t.user_id
FROM (
SELECT c.user_id as user_id, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_bestof b WHERE b.user_id = c.user_id) as bCount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_pair   p WHERE p.user_id = c.user_id) as pCount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_findme_style  s WHERE s.user_id = c.user_id) as sCount
FROM jos_findme c ) t ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT c.user_id, sum(b.count(*)+p.count(*)+s.count(*)) as totalcount 
    from jos_findme c 
    join  jos_findme_bestof b 
        on b.user_id = c.user_id 
    join jos_findme_pair p 
        on p.user_id = c.user_id 
    join jos_findme_style  s 
        on s.user_id = c.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.user_id, 
      (IFNULL(b.bCount, 0) + IFNULL(p.pCount, 0) + IFNULL(s.sCount, 0)) AS totalCount
FROM jos_findme c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.user_id, COUNT(1) bCount 
           FROM jos_findme_bestof b 
           GROUP BY b.user_id 
         ) AS b ON b.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.user_id, COUNT(1) pCount 
           FROM jos_findme_pair p 
           GROUP BY p.user_id 
         ) AS p ON p.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT s.user_id, COUNT(1) sCount 
           FROM jos_findme_style s 
           GROUP BY s.user_id
         ) AS s ON s.user_id = c.user_id
```